# In java, how do i replace integer value in cookie value?

Tags: java, string, parsing, session

I have a cookie value like SESSIONID_TEST=4CEC1E0609F127DD7EB87DD438B2CA50.jap-test-lad-14; path=/

Now i want to replace only 14(which is dynamic value) with different number for example 19.

So I want the cookie value to be and also remove "; path=/" and text "SESSIONID_TEST="

4CEC1E0609F127DD7EB87DD438B2CA50.jap-test-lad-19

Let me know
much appreciated

Comment: is the cookie value a string?

Comment: @sgamer OK, so where's the problem? Replacing parts of `String` objects should not be the big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use this?

```
cookie.replace("14; path=/", "19");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can we do this by one line of code. Sorry i forgot to mention i do not want "SESSIONID_TEST=" as well. So my final cookie should be 4CEC1E0609F127DD7EB87DD438B2CA50.jap-test-lad-19

Comment: Then it shoud be: cookie.replace("14; path=/", "19").replace("SESSIONID_TEST=", "");

Comment: Thanks..
 
Sorry lastly, value 14 in the cookie value is dynamic so how can i get that value and replace with any number?

Answer (score 1):

use `String.replace()`. It takes two arguments. The first one is the old string you want to change and the second is what you want to change it to.

`cookie = cookie.replace("14; path=/", "19")`

will make cookie = `SESSIONID_TEST=4CEC1E0609F127DD7EB87DD438B2CA50.jap-test-lad-19`

**Be careful though**

```
String x = "101010";
x.replace("1", "2");
System.out.println(x);
```

Will print "101010" because strings are immutable. You have to make a new  string or call

`x = x.replace()`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

"The String class has a number of methods, some of which will be discussed below, that appear to modify strings. Since strings are immutable, what these methods really do is create and return a new string that contains the result of the operation."

EDIT:

Since "14" changes you can use slicing instead of `String.replace()`. Assuming "14" will always be in the same spot and always be the same length use this instead:`cookie = cookie[0 : (len(cookie) - 10)] + "19"` Also remember to replace "sessionid_test" with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can we do this by one line of code. Sorry i forgot to mention i do not want "SESSIONID_TEST=" as well. So my final cookie should be 4CEC1E0609F127DD7EB87DD438B2CA50.jap-test-lad-19

Comment: easy, just call the `replace` method again like this: `cookie = cookie.replace("SESSIONID_TEST=", "")` This replaces the first argument with an empty string or, nothing you could say

Comment: Sorry lastly, value 14 in the cookie value is dynamic so how can i get that value and replace with any number?

Comment: Will the cookie length always be the same? and will the value at 14 always be 2 digits? If no to both the question gets a lot more difficult

Comment: yes the value will always be 2 digits and length will be same

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a `String` and put it in a variable `str` and then use the following code snippet -

```
str.replace("14", "19")
str.replace("; path=/" , "");
str.replace("SESSIONID_TEST=", "");
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can we do this by one line of code. Sorry i forgot to mention i do not want "SESSIONID_TEST=" as well. So my final cookie should be 4CEC1E0609F127DD7EB87DD438B2CA50.jap-test-lad-19

Comment: Sorry lastly, value 14 in the cookie value is dynamic so how can i get that value and replace with any number?